# SQL Server : return rows containing multiple string in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve all the rows which contain any of comma separated string passed in stored procedure parameter. But problem in my code is that it returns all the rows which contain **any** of the comma separated string, instead of **all** comma separated string.

The below code only has 2 strings but there could be many comma separated strings.
In the real world, the user can have multiple column and I should be able to search multiple comma separated string in that table. So my stored procedure should return rows which contain all the comma separated search strings.

Table:

```
Exchange    Ticker
------------------
NASDAQ      GOOG
NASDAQ      APPL
NASDAQ      MSFT
NYSE        IBM
NASDAQ      AMZN
NYSE        FB
```

Stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @searchStr VARCHAR(500) = 'NASDAQ,GOOG'

CREATE TABLE #TSearchString (tempStr VARCHAR(100))

WHILE LEN(@searchStr) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(100)

    IF CHARINDEX(',',@searchStr) > 0
        SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@searchStr, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr))
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = @searchStr
        SET @searchStr = ''
    END

    INSERT INTO #TSearchString 
    VALUES (@temp)

    SET @searchStr = REPLACE(@searchStr,@temp + ',' , '')
 END

 SELECT * 
 FROM stocks 
 WHERE Exchange IN (SELECT tempStr FROM #TSearchString) 
    OR ticker IN (SELECT tempStr FROM #TSearchString)
```

Current result:

```
Exchange    ticker
-------------------
NASDAQ      GOOG
NASDAQ      APPL
NASDAQ      MSFT
NASDAQ      AMZN
```

Expected result:

```
Exchange    ticker
-------------------
NASDAQ      GOOG
```

When `DECLARE @searchStr VARCHAR(500) = 'NASDAQ'` expected result is that the stored procedure should return all the rows which contain 'NASDAQ'.

```
Exchange    ticker
--------------------
NASDAQ      GOOG
NASDAQ      APPL
NASDAQ      MSFT
NASDAQ      AMZN
```

Comment: Are you looking fo splitting the string and put it in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Yes, That is the reason i created temp table and was trying to execute all select query for all the comma separated string...Any alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
DECLARE @searchStr VARCHAR(500) = 'NASDAQ,GOOG';

SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE T.Exchange = LEFT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) - 1)
AND T.Ticker = RIGHT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr)-3)
```

Or

```
DECLARE @searchStr VARCHAR(500) = 'NASDAQ,GOOG,NYSE,IBM';

SELECT T.*
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,
          value V
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchStr, ',')
  ) T1 JOIN
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN,
          value V
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchStr, ',')
  ) T2
  ON T1.RN + 1 = T2.RN
  JOIN T
  ON T.Exchange = T1.V
     AND
     T.Ticker = T2.V;
```

---

*UPDATE:*

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE 
( 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) > 0 
         THEN LEFT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) - 1)
         ELSE @searchStr
    END = T. Exchange
)
AND
(
  (T.Ticker IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) = 0)
  OR
  (
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) > 0
         THEN RIGHT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr)-3)
         END = T.Ticker
  )
)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d285c68f71cf7096fca479849f09fc3)**

and you can create a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunc 
(@searchStr VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  SELECT *
  FROM T 
  WHERE 
  ( 
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) > 0 
           THEN LEFT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) - 1)
           ELSE @searchStr
      END = T. Exchange
  )
  AND
  (
    (T.Ticker IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) = 0)
    OR
    (
      CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr) > 0
           THEN RIGHT(@searchStr, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr)-3)
           END = T.Ticker
    )
  )
```

and then just

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunc('NYSE');
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunc('NASDAQ,GOOG');
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cba4225bb7eae3be5b94d7e06bd500c6)**

---

> Finally, if that doesn't feet your requirements, then I suggest you use a **[`Table-Valued Parameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)** instead of the comma delimited string.

Comment: It will not work for the same as IsItGreyOrGray's answer and there is possibility that there can be many comma separated string and not just 2.Updated the question

Comment: As mentioned in question my problem is that sp should return rows which contain all the comma separated string among all the columns in table. In your second it should not return any row which now row contain all four values 'NASDAQ,GOOG,NYSE,IBM' but it will return two rows.

Comment: How it's not working? please check the demo @A.Learn

Comment: So far @Sami is hitting all the requirements with the possible exception of the four value one... but if your table only has the two columns, how can it return a row with four values?

Comment: This was the sample table...@Sami solution have assumptions that there is only going to be 2 columns. Table can have 5 columns and search string can have 3 comma separated string in that case only rows which has all three search string should be returned.This is my scenario ...Current table was just to illustrate the example but my table contain many columns

Comment: @A.Learn That wasn't your question and you did not mention that before.

Comment: My apologies, I thought i did in very first para of my question and in first comment to your answer.I'll update the question for more clarity

Comment: @Sami I see that you mentioned to use table valued parameter, but how thats going to help as you can see in my question in my current solution i am able to create temp table which has all the search string, but i am not able find a way to select a row which contain all the rows of tempTable which is search strings

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer I came up with which is not efficient but works

```
DECLARE @searchStr VARCHAR(500) = 'NASDAQ,GOOG'
create table #TempOne (Exchange varchar(50), ticker varchar(10))
create table #TempTwo (Exchange varchar(50), ticker varchar(10))
insert into #TempOne select * from stocks
WHILE LEN(@searchStr) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(100)
    IF CHARINDEX(',',@searchStr) > 0
        SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@searchStr, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @searchStr))
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = @searchStr
        SET @searchStr = ''
    END
    Declare @temp1 varchar(100)
    set @temp1 = '%'+ @temp + '%'
    insert into #TempTwo select * from #TempOne where ticker like @temp1 or Exchange like @temp1
    delete #TempOne
    insert into #TempOne select * from #TempTwo
    delete #TempTwo
    SET @searchStr = REPLACE(@searchStr,@temp + ',' , '')
 END

 select * from #TempOne
```